# Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure with user type object in plain query

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've some stored procedure in Oracle database - GetBalance.  Single input parameter is custom user type

```
create or replace TYPE XXX_INPUT_PARAM as object (
  CUSTOMER_CODE VARCHAR2(2000),
  DATA_START VARCHAR2(10),
  DATA_END VARCHAR2(10),
)
```

I want to use this in plain query. Something like this:

```
select * from table(bigOraclePackage.GetBalance('12345', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-06'))
```

Is it possible? How can i do it? I've try:

```
SELECT bigOraclePackage.GetBalance(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT '12345','2023-04-01', '2023-04-06' from DUAL) as XXX_INP_PARAM)) FROM DUAL
```

but catched ORA-22907  "invalid CAST to a type that is not a nested table or VARRAY"

I can't use stored procedure or function. I can't edit or change or create new database objects.

Comment: What is the return type of your function (nor procedure, presumably)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your function returns a scalar number - based on its name - then you can call it as:

```
select bigOraclePackage.GetBalance(xxx_input_param('12345', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-06'))
from dual
```

That creates an object using the literal values, and passes that object to the function; and as a select-list item.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e-l5osVn)

You can select from any table - with fixed values `dual` makes sense, but if you're getting the values from some other table then you can query against that and use the column names in the object call.

Comment: Yeah this thing is working. But i get other issue. This procedure return not scalar result, but other custom type. As i understood - this procedure doing some insert in temporary tables or somthing else. I got "ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query tips".

Comment: That's a completely different issue to your question. If your function is doing DML then you can't really call it from a query, but you can call it from within a PL/SQL block, assigning the result to a PL/SQL variable (of that other object type).